# Multiple Table Join For Search Query PHP & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm still facing problem with multiple table joining in MySQL. I want to make a search with multiple tables, here I have 8 tables & I want to join all tables together to get all values from 8 tables while searching my site. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance. [N.B: All Table Formats Are Similar

Comment: Now that you have described your problem. Let us see some code so that we can actually help

Comment: Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from A
join B
on A.c1 = B.c2
join C 
on B.c3 = C.c4
join D
on C.c5 = D.c6
join E
on D.c7 = E.c8
join F
on E.c9 = F.c10
join G
on F.c11 = G.c12
join H
on G.c13 = H.c14
```

Replace large letters with your tables and ci with the corresponding column. Join criteria can be virtually anything, for simplicity's sake I have chosen equality of columns